# Improve speed of database creation that uses xml strings in Android

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, bulkinsert

I am creating an app aimed at API 17 with a single database that when finished will have between 300-700 rows that are very text heavy. I have initially chosen to create my database programmatically saving the text to be added to the database as string in xml files found in res/values strings files.

I have read the conversations regarding using DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper() which I am aware is deprecated and SQLite Statement however I do not understand how to change my current code in such a way to improve the performance when populating my database.

My main acitivity code relating to the database is as follows:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
    implements //implementations for various fragments

public LawDbAdapter dbHelper;
LawDbAdapter db;

public SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //code for creating the fragment and inflating the view

    openDatabase();
    }

private void openDatabase() {
    db = new LawDbAdapter(this);

    db.open();
    //Clean all data
    db.deleteAllEntries();
    //Add some data
    db.insertSomeEntrys();  
}

private void showInfoNamedCursor(String namedCursor) {
    Cursor cursor = db.fetchEntriesByName(namedCursor);
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
    String d;
    String e;
    String f;

    a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("aaa"));
    b = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("bbb"));
    c = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ccc"));
    d = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ddd"));
    e = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("eee"));
    f = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fff"));

    onLawSelected(0,  name,  section,  act,  definition,  arrest,  detain); 
}
```

My Database Adapter code is as follows:

```
    public class LawDbAdapter {

//static variables for the ROW NAMES of the Law table


//TAG for Log prints
private static final String TAG = "LawDbAdapter";

//db and db helpers
private static DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

//Database and table name/version
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Legislation";
private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Law";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//reference to the current context
private final Context mCtx;

//String to create the database if it does not already exist
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
    KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
    KEY_SECTION + "," +
    KEY_NAME + "," +
    KEY_DEFINITION + "," +
    KEY_ACT + "," +
    KEY_ARREST + ","+
    KEY_KEYWORDS + ","+
    KEY_GROUP + "," +
    KEY_DETAINABLE +
    ");"
    ;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {

        // Use the application context, which will ensure that you 
        // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
        // See this article for more information: http://bit.ly/6LRzfx
        if (mDbHelper == null) {
            mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
            Log.d("DBADAPTER", "NEW DATABASE HELPER OBJECT CREATED");

        }
        return mDbHelper;
    } 


    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
        //create database
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        System.out.println("onCreate()  DATABASE CREATED " + db.toString());


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        //drop old table
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
        //call on create ot create new table
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public LawDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    //reference current context
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public LawDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    DatabaseHelper.getInstance(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    System.out.println("LawDb Adapter opne()   DATABASE ADAPTER " + this.toString());
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

/**
 * creates a new Law in the Law Table and puts in the Strings passed into a new ROW
 * @param section
 * @param name
 * @param definition
 * @param act
 * @param arrest
 * @param keywords
 * @param group
 * @return
 */
public long createEntry(String section, String name, 
        String definition, String act, String arrest, String keywords, String group, String detention) {

    System.out.println("createEntry()");
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_SECTION, section);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, definition);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ACT, act);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ARREST, arrest);
    initialValues.put(KEY_KEYWORDS, keywords);
    initialValues.put(KEY_GROUP, group);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DETAINABLE, detention);


    return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//delete all laws in the table
public boolean deleteAllEntries() {
    int doneDelete = 0;
    doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
    Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete)+ " deleteAllLaws()");
    return doneDelete > 0;
}

/*
 * returns a whole row of SQLITE_TABLE in alphabetical order. if inputtext is null or 0 length then no selection is performed.
 * IF a string has been passed then any ROWs that NAME contains the input text will be displayed, still in alphabetical order.
 */
public Cursor fetchEntriesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.d(TAG, inputText + " fetchLawsByName()");
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    //will not filter if the parameter is null or of no length
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_SECTION, KEY_NAME, KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_ACT, KEY_ARREST, KEY_KEYWORDS, KEY_GROUP, KEY_DETAINABLE}, 
                null, null, null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC");
    }
    else {
        //will filter the items showing only those that contain the filter parameter within the name ie dru in drugs.
        mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_SECTION, KEY_NAME, KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_ACT, KEY_ARREST, KEY_KEYWORDS, KEY_GROUP, KEY_DETAINABLE}, 
                KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC", null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//returns laws based on a filter by keywords
public Cursor fetchEntriesByKeyword(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText + " fetchLawsByKeyword()");
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    //will not filter if the parameter is null or of no length
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_SECTION, KEY_NAME, KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_ACT, KEY_ARREST, KEY_KEYWORDS, KEY_GROUP, KEY_DETAINABLE}, 
                null, null, null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC");
    }
    else {
        //will filter the items showing only those that contain the filter parameter within the name ie dru in drugs.
        mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_SECTION, KEY_NAME, KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_ACT, KEY_ARREST, KEY_KEYWORDS, KEY_GROUP, KEY_DETAINABLE}, 
                KEY_KEYWORDS + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC", null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//will fetch all entries in alphabetical order
public Cursor fetchAllEntries() {
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_SECTION, KEY_NAME, KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_ACT, KEY_ARREST, KEY_KEYWORDS, KEY_GROUP, KEY_DETAINABLE}, 
            null, null, null, null,  KEY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

/*
 * returns a whole row of SQLITE_TABLE in alphabetical order. if inputtext is null or 0 length then no selection is performed.
 * IF a string has been passed then any ROWs that ACT contains the input text will be displayed, still in alphabetical order.
 */
public Cursor fetchEntriesByAct(String inputText){
    Log.w(TAG, inputText + " fetchLawsByAct()");
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    //will not filter if the parameter is null or of no length
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_SECTION, KEY_NAME, KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_ACT, KEY_ARREST, KEY_KEYWORDS, KEY_GROUP, KEY_DETAINABLE}, 
                null, null, null, null, KEY_ACT);
    }
    else {
        //will filter the items showing only those that contain the filter parameter within the name ie dru in drugs.
        mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_SECTION, KEY_NAME, KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_ACT, KEY_ARREST, KEY_KEYWORDS, KEY_GROUP, KEY_DETAINABLE}, 
                KEY_ACT + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, KEY_ACT, null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}


/*
 * returns a whole row of SQLITE_TABLE in alphabetical order. if inputtext is null or 0 length all rows in the passed GROUP 
 * are displayed. IF a string has been passed then any ROWs that NAME contains the input text will be displayed, still in alphabetical order.
 * and in the originally passed group
 */
public Cursor fetchEntriesByGroup(String group, String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText + " fetchLawsByGroup()");
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    //will not filter by search if the parameter is null or of no length
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_SECTION, KEY_NAME, KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_ACT, KEY_ARREST, KEY_KEYWORDS, KEY_GROUP, KEY_DETAINABLE}, 
                KEY_GROUP + " like '%" + group + "%'", null, null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC");
        //where KEY_GROUP = group
    }
    else {
        //will filter the items showing only those that contain the filter parameter within the name ie dru in drugs.
        mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_SECTION, KEY_NAME, KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_ACT, KEY_ARREST, KEY_KEYWORDS, KEY_GROUP, KEY_DETAINABLE}, 
                KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%' AND "+ KEY_GROUP + " like '%" + group + "%'", null,
                null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC", null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}


//untested deleteMethod
public void deleteNamedEntry(String entryName) {

    mDb.delete(DATABASE_NAME, KEY_NAME + "= ?" + entryName, null);
}


//this method creates all the laws in the table, it does so by referring to strings in  R.java. Each line is is one law.
public void insertSomeEntrys() {

    System.out.println("insertSomeEntries()");
    //COPY PASTE SAMPLES
    //      MNEMONIC    createEntry(null,MNEMONICNAME,DEFINITION,TOPIC,null,TAGS,GROUP, null);
    //      LAW         createEntry(section,name,definition,act,arrest,tags,group, detention);
    //      createLaw(null, name, definition, null,null,tags,group,null);
    //                  mCtx.getString(R.string
    //     DRUG        createEntry(null,NAME,DEFINITION,NICKNAMES,null,TAGS,GROUP, null);

    //SIGNS OF INTOXICATION
    createEntry(null,mCtx.getString(R.string.signs_of_intoxication_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.signs_of_intoxication_definition),null,null,mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),null, null);

    //PROCEDURAL ENTRIES (MAY BELONG TO SEVERAL SECTIONS) 


    //full detention; procedures/basic/law
    createEntry(mCtx.getString(R.string.detention_section),mCtx.getString(R.string.detention_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.full_detention_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.criminal_procedure_scotland_act),null,mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_procedures) + " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_basic)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    //human rights; procedures/basic/law
    createEntry(mCtx.getString(R.string.human_rights_section),mCtx.getString(R.string.human_rights_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.human_rights_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.human_rights_act),mCtx.getString(R.string.human_rights_arrest),mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_procedures)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_basic)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    //S13 requirement; procedures/basic/law
    createEntry(mCtx.getString(R.string.S13_section),mCtx.getString(R.string.S13_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.S13_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.criminal_procedure_scotland_act),mCtx.getString(R.string.S13_arrest),mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_procedures)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_basic)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), mCtx.getString(R.string.detain_no));
    //full arrest without warrant commonlaw and statute ; prcedures/basic/law
    createEntry(null, mCtx.getString(R.string.full_arrest_without_warrant_name), mCtx.getString(R.string.full_arrest_without_warrant_definition), mCtx.getString(R.string.full_arrest_without_warrant_act), null, mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_procedures)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_basic)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    //S18 CP(S)A; procedures/law
    createEntry(mCtx.getString(R.string.S18_section),mCtx.getString(R.string.S18_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.S18_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.criminal_procedure_scotland_act),null,mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_procedures)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    //entry to premises common law; procedures;basic/law
    createEntry(null , mCtx.getString(R.string.entry_to_premises_common_law_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.entry_to_premises_common_law_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law),null, mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_procedures)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_basic)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    //breach of bail; procedures;basic/law
    createEntry(mCtx.getString(R.string.breach_of_bail_section),mCtx.getString(R.string.breach_of_bail_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.breach_of_bail_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.criminal_procedure_scotland_act),mCtx.getString(R.string.breach_of_bail_arrest),mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_procedures)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_basic)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), mCtx.getString(R.string.detain_yes));
    //cross border powers; procedures/law
    createEntry(mCtx.getString(R.string.cross_border_arrest_section),mCtx.getString(R.string.cross_border_arrest_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.cross_border_arrest_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.criminal_justice_and_public_order_act),null,mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_procedures)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);

    //CRIMES

    //COMMON LAW
    //Theft; crime/law/basic
    createEntry(null,mCtx.getString(R.string.theft_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.theft_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law),mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law_arrest),mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime) + " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_basic) + " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), mCtx.getString(R.string.detain_yes));
    //Theft HB; crime/law
    createEntry(null,mCtx.getString(R.string.theft_HB_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.theft_HB_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law),mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law_arrest),mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law) + " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime), mCtx.getString(R.string.detain_yes));
    //Att Theft HBWI; crime;law
    createEntry(null,mCtx.getString(R.string.Att_Theft_HBWI_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.Att_Theft_HBWI_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law),mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law_arrest),mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law) + " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime), mCtx.getString(R.string.detain_yes));
    //HBWI; crime/law
    createEntry(null,mCtx.getString(R.string.HBWI_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.HBWI_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law),mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law_arrest),mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law) + " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime), mCtx.getString(R.string.detain_yes));



    //MISUSE OF DRUGS ACT
    //drugs(possession); crime /law
    createEntry("5(2) ","Possession of a Controlled Drug","Drugs are Bad M-Kay",mCtx.getString(R.string.misuse_of_drugs_act),"a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), mCtx.getString(R.string.detain_yes));
    //drugs(search); search/law
    createEntry("23 ","Search Power - Drugs","Police can search you for drugs, deal with it",mCtx.getString(R.string.misuse_of_drugs_act),"a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_search)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);



    //ROAD TRAFFIC ACT
    //drink driving; traffic/law
    createEntry("5 ","Drink Driving","Driving Drunk is a crime",mCtx.getString(R.string.road_traffic_act),"a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_traffic)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    //Take MV without authority; traffic/law
    createEntry(mCtx.getString(R.string.s178_motor_vehicle_section),mCtx.getString(R.string.s178_motor_vehicle_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.s178_motor_vehicle_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.road_traffic_act),mCtx.getString(R.string.s178_motor_vehicle_arrest),mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law) + " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_traffic), mCtx.getString(R.string.detain_yes));


    //CRIMINAL LAW CONSOLIDATION SCOTLAND ACT
    //vandalism; crime/law/civilorder
    createEntry(mCtx.getString(R.string.law_vandalism_section),mCtx.getString(R.string.law_vandalism_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.law_vandalism_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.criminal_law_consolidation_scotland_act),mCtx.getString(R.string.law_vandalism_arrest)+ " "+ mCtx.getString(R.string.common_law_arrest),mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime) + " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_civil_order)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), mCtx.getString(R.string.detain_yes));

    //TEMP CRIME

    createEntry("Section 1 ","Sexual Crime","definition of a sexual crime","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_sexual)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 4 ","Crime Crime","definition of a crime crime","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 5 ","People Crime","definition of a people crime","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_people)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 6 ","Civil Crime","definition of a civil crime","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_civil_order)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 7 ","Licensing Crime","definition of a licensing crime","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_licensing)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 8 ","Terrorism Crime","definition","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_terrorism)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 9 ","Animal Crime","definition","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_animals)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 0 ","Crime","definition","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_firearms)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 12 ","Crime","definition","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_terrorism)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 11  ","Crime","definition","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_animals)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 13 ","Crime","definition","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 14 ","Crime","definition","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);
    createEntry("Section 15 ","Crime","definition","act","a",mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_crime)+ " " + mCtx.getString(R.string.group_law), null);

    //MNEMONICS
    createEntry(null,mCtx.getString(R.string.mnemonic_DRABC_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.mnemonic_DRABC_definition),mCtx.getString(R.string.mnemonic_DRABC_topic),null,mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_mnemonic), null);

    //DRUGS
    createEntry(null,mCtx.getString(R.string.drug_cannabis_name),mCtx.getString(R.string.drug_cannabis_description),mCtx.getString(R.string.drug_cannabis_nicknames),null,mCtx.getString(R.string.test_tag),mCtx.getString(R.string.group_drug), null); }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have initially chosen to create my database programmatically saving the text to be added to the database as string in xml files found in res/values strings files

Unless you are using string resources to allow for translations, you are probably better served by shipping a pre-packaged SQLite database, [perhaps using `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

> I have read the conversations regarding using DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper() which I am aware is deprecated and SQLite Statement however I do not understand how to change my current code in such a way to improve the performance when populating my database.

I doubt that either of those are your problem. Your problem is that you are not using transactions. Modify `insertSomeEntrys()` to use a transaction:

```
public void insertSomeEntrys() {
  try {
    mDb.beginTransaction();

    // insert all of your current code here

    mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
  }
  finally {
     mDb.endTransaction();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: Using transactions made a different to the performance thanks. I will investigate the other option as well, cheers Commons